# What is $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(\bar {z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, gamma-function

Is there an identity  for $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(\bar {z})$?

Post-question edits:

Have you come across any, in addition to [the ones listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)? (there, special cases, where the real part of $z$ is integer or half integer, are also listed.)

[Abramowitz-Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_257.htm)  lists the following under 6.1.45 $$\lim_{|y|\to \infty} (2\pi)^{-1/2} |\Gamma (z)| e^{\pi|y|/2} |y|^{1/2-x} =1$$

Answer (score 6):

Since $\Gamma(\bar{z}) = \overline{\Gamma(z)}$ $$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(\bar{z})=\Gamma(z)\overline{\Gamma(z)} = |\Gamma(z)|^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $z=x+iy$,
$$\Gamma[z] \Gamma[\bar z|=|\Gamma(x+iy)|^2=\Gamma^2(x) \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{y^2}{(x+n)^2} \right)^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh! yes it should be -1, i have corrected it. Thanks.