# Properties of functions satisfying the functional equation $f(x+iy)=f(x-iy)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-functions

Consider the analytic function $f(z)$ satisfying :

$$f(z)=f(\bar{z})$$

i.e.  $$f(x+iy)=f(x-iy)$$

We can consider the case of real valued function, with real and  complex domain, satisfy the above condition .

> > Question :
> >
> > (1)What are some non trivial properties of such  class of functions ?
> >
> > (2)What are some noteworthy examples of such functions?

Comment: [Not too long ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3561665), we had someone point out that the Gamma function belongs to this class.

Comment: @user754697 No gamma function doesn't belong to this category. Please read the question again

Answer (score 4):

$f $ is analytic iff  $\frac{df(z)}{d\bar{z}}=0$.  So your property of interest implies $0=\frac{df(\bar{z})}{d\bar{z}}=f'(\bar{z})$, which means $f'$ is zero, ergo $f $ is constant.

Comment: For completeness, the derivative here is called a Wirtinger derivative.  You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives

Answer (score 1):

Define:$f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ by $$f(z)=z.\bar{z}+iz.\bar{z}$$ and you'll get what you want

Comment: The function you propose is not analytic. In this case, functions are asked to be analytic.