# Closed form for $\Gamma (a+bi)\Gamma(a-bi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, closed-form, gamma-function

I noticed that
$$\Gamma (3+2i)\Gamma (3-2i)=\frac{160\pi}{e^{2\pi}-e^{-2\pi}}$$
and
$$\Gamma (2+5i)\Gamma (2-5i)=\frac{260\pi}{e^{5\pi}-e^{-5\pi}}.$$
Is there a closed form for $\Gamma (a+bi)\Gamma (a-bi)$ in general?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3561660

Comment: But how do I get the exponentials from $\Gamma (z)\Gamma (\overline{z})=|\Gamma (z)|^2$?

Comment: You may see my answer of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561660/what-is-gammaz-gamma-bar-z/3561857#3561857

Comment: But how would you prove that e.g. $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \left(1+\frac{4}{(3+n)^2}\right)=\frac{e^{2\pi}-e^{-2\pi}}{40\pi}$?

Comment: The link you mentioned does not answer my question, as it does not prove nor provide the closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closed form you seek exists if $2a\in\Bbb Z$.

Since $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi\csc\pi s$, $\Gamma(is)\Gamma(1-is)=-i\pi\operatorname{csch}\pi s$, so $\Gamma(is)\Gamma(-is)=\frac{\pi}{s}\operatorname{csch}\pi s$. Then$$\frac{\Gamma(1+is)\Gamma(1-is)}{\Gamma(is)\Gamma(-is)}=s^2,\,\frac{\Gamma(2+is)\Gamma(2-is)}{\Gamma(1+is)\Gamma(1-is)}=1+s^2,\,\frac{\Gamma(3+is)\Gamma(3-is)}{\Gamma(2+is)\Gamma(2-is)}=4+s^2.$$

Comment: Looks like: $$\Gamma (a-i b) \Gamma (a+i b)=\pi*  b* \text{csch}(\pi  b) *\prod _{n=1}^{a-1}
   \left(n^2+b^2\right)$$ if: $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk If you change your first $\pi b$ to $\frac{\pi}{b}$ and your $n=1$ to $n=0$, you can include the case $a=0$. To include negative $a$ requires a separate calculation where we divide out a product of quadratics. The formula for $\Gamma(is)\Gamma(1-is)$ lets us handle odd $2a$.

Comment: Ok. thanks :)  :)